# DBCC CHECKIDENT ('table name', RESEED, 20000) not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When I run the script

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('table name', RESEED, 20000)
```

the output of the message is

> Checking identity information: current identity value '200000', current
>    column value '200000'. DBCC Execution completed. If DBCC printed error
>    messages, contact your system administrator.

When I query the identity value by running

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('table_name')
```

it is showing up as 200000 as expected, however, when the developer inserts records into the table, it's not using the new reseeded value.

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 5):

It turns out after multiple conversations with the developers of this application using the table that there was a 'hidden' stored procedure that was grabbing the maximum value of the ID column in the table and adding an arbitrary number to it then issuing an IDENTITY_INSERT statement resulting in the newly reseeded value.

Answer (score 2):

To long for a comment but, if you look a few pages down in the [MSDN entry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx) you will see the following:

[image]

It looks like the second option is unlikely in your case but is the first a possibility?